# Change JSX code style in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm, jsx

I am using the airbnb ESLint extension in my React project that forces me to format empty/void tags with a space in between: `<br />`.

However, WebStorm auto formatting (Prettier) changes this every time. I do not find JSX in the WebStorm Code Style settings (`File > Settings > Code Style`).

Is there a way I can change the JSX formatting settings of WebStorm? Could a `.editorconfig` file help?

Comment: Have you tried [enabling ESLint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html)?

Comment: Sure ESLint is enabled but that does not change how Webstorm formats the code, right? It just highlights the ESLint errors. I need a way to configure how Webstorm auto formats JSX code...

Comment: Eslint has a fix command [you should be able to use in Webstorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24452#comment=27-1763733) but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Using ESLint --fix instead of prettier does not sound right but I will give it a shot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Might be worth looking into. I don't have that much Webstorm experience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebStorm own JSX formatting respects HTML code style preferences - in particular, to have your self-closing JSX tags formatted as `<br />`, you have to enable **In empty tag** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**, **Spaces**.

Prettier doesn't use WebStorm code preferences though... and it used to insert a space in empty tags on formatting, as far as I can tell (https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1985)

Comment: thanks @lena. I just found that out like 5 min ago as you can tell from my own answer to my question. I will give you the answer tag anyways!

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution to my problem. It was actually just a HTML formatting thing and not related to JSX meaning that Webstorm will use the HTML formatting rules to style the JSX accordingly.

`Files > Editor > Code Style > HTML` under the option `Spaces` the checkbox `In empty tag` will style empty/void tags like the airbnb extensions want it to be.

For further styling rules, I will definelty have a look at prettierrc.json as suggested by @Ales Dostál.

Answer (score 1):

You can add file ".prettierignore" to your project. You can set ignore all files to disable prettier.

But better way is using Prettier as primary tool for formating code. In file ".prettierrc.json" you can set custom settings.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will definetly have a look at .prettierrc.json and what it can do in conjunction with Webstorm.